# Do I need to manage the shards myself when communicating with Elasticsearch using java client?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am kind of a newbie on Elasticsearch and currently playing with ES 5.0.1. In the ES documents, Transport Client chapter, the tutorial code is like this:

```
>// on startup
>
>TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
>        .addTransportAddress(new >InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host1"), 9300))
>        .addTransportAddress(new >InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host2"), 9300));
>
>// on shutdown
>
>client.close();
```

My question is, do I need to use different host IP (InetAddress) when I wish to put new data in a specific shard? Or if I only use one host as the portal, what could happen?